# Python __init__ method losing self pointer. Very strange

Tags: python

```
class RectangularRoom(object):
    """
    A RectangularRoom represents a rectangular region containing clean or dirty
    tiles.

    A room has a width and a height and contains (width * height) tiles. At any
    particular time, each of these tiles is either clean or dirty.
    """

    class Tile:
        def __init__(self,tilewidth,tileheight):
            self.tilewidth=tilewidth
            self.tileheight=tileheight
            self.isclean=false

    def __init__(self, initwidth,initheight):
        """
        Initializes a rectangular room with the specified width and height.

        Initially, no tiles in the room have been cleaned.

        width: an integer > 0
        height: an integer > 0
        """
        self.width=initwidth
        self.height=initheight
        self.tileslist=[]
        for i in range(self.width+1):
            for j in range(self.height+1):
                tileslist.add(Tile(i,j))
```

In the above code, in the line `for j in range(self.height+1):`, the `self` pointer is lost,
as I found in pdb debugger

```
->for j in range(self.height+1):
(Pdb) p self
<ps2a.RectangularRoom object at 0x7f925c1d10d0>
(Pdb) s
NameError: "global name 'height' is not defined"
> <string>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) p self
*** NameError: NameError("name 'self' is not defined",)
(Pdb) $
```

I found that to be very strange (even alienlike). Any thoughts?

Comment: This is NOT your problem, just an observation -- class Tile is declared somewhat unusually. I'd recommend moving it outside of the RectangularRoom class definition. Or even better, get rid of it altogether and use a simple dict()

Answer (score 5):

You changed your source code *while running the script*. Restart your Python session, the source and actual bytecode being run are out of sync. This is why you get a `NameError` exception for a global name `height`, while your source code is using an attribute instead.

Tools like `pdb` load the source code for listing lines *on demand*, while Python only loads the code once at the start, compiles it into bytecode and runs that. So you started with a line like `for j in range(height+1):`, started Python with that, saved a new version with `self.` added, and then when you got to the loop in the debugger, `pdb` loaded that changed line from disk.

Once the exception is thrown, you are dropped out of the `__init__` method context; you are now at `<string>(1)<module>()->None`, not your `for` loop. There is no `self` local name in that scope.

Comment: Thanks, now in need some other murky issues in the pile of trash that